# How to exclude Dagger2 classes from test coverage

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, jacoco, dagger-2

Is there any option to exclude Dagger2 classes from test coverage report in Android Studio

Comment: You mean classes generated by dagger-compiler apt or your modules and components? Connected or unit tests?

Comment: classes generated by dagger

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### JaCoCo excludes

If you're using JaCoCo, for example using android instrumentation **connected tests**, you need to configure the **excludes** (or includes), which, according to the [documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html#excludes) is...

> A list of class files to exclude from the report. May use wildcard characters (* and ?). When not specified nothing will be excluded.

Which means you need to match the generated dagger class names. The following rules cover virtually any class generated by `dagger-compiler`, without matching any of non-generated classes (unless you name your class the same as dagger does...):

```
excludes = [
    '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
    '**/Dagger*Component.class', // covers component implementations
    '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.class', // covers component builders
    '**/*Module_*Factory.class'
]
```

You can check your generated dagger classes in `app/build/generated/source/apt` directory after running a build, to see if there are any additional generated classes that you want to match with excludes.

This **excludes** array is a configuration property of jacoco plugin. Now, where to put this `excludes` array depends on whether you define your own tasks based on the jacoco plugin, or use a 'higher level plugin' that does this for you. For example using [this plugin](https://github.com/arturdm/jacoco-android-gradle-plugin) (you can see the plugin source to see where the excludes are actually applied):

```
jacocoAndroidUnitTestReport {
  excludes +=  [
        '**/*_MembersInjector.class',
        '**/Dagger*Component.class',
        '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.class',
        '**/*Module_*Factory.class'
    ]
}
```

#### Connected tests

If you're running android connected test coverage by setting `testCoverageEnabled true` in your **buildType**, unfortunately there is no idiomatic way to declare **excludes**, since the [android gradle plugin](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/) doesn't provide such options, and the predefined [jacoco report task](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/03842a2bd83ffcee6c1b8649ae6dbe038e29bf2c/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/coverage/JacocoReportTask.groovy) has the excludes hardcoded. In this case, you have to script your own task with **excludes**.

---

### IntelliJ test runner

If you're using the IntelliJ test runner, whether the coverage is done by IntelliJ or JaCoCo, you need to put the **includes** for a test configuration.

1. Open the **Edit Configurations** window:

[image: Edit Configurations]

2. Choose your test config and define includes (classes or whole packages). In this case I included the whole `com.google.android.gms` package, just as an example:

[image: Test coverage includes]

To **exclude** dagger generated files, the quickest way is to put all the dagger dependencies in one root package, and **include** all the **other** packages in the test configuration.

Comment: What is $Builder in '**/Dagger*Component$Builder.class' ?

Answer (score 10):

### Exclude files from AndroidStudio index

After many days I found solution: **exclusion files from IDE index also exclude them from IDE's code coverage report.**
So we need create new File-Type for all codegen files (or only Dagger/Hilt files), and exclude this File-Type from index.

To achieve this you need:

##### 1. Create new File-Type 'Codegen' for codegen-files

Go to `Preferences -> File Types`, and add new file-type `Codegen`:
[image: create new file-type]

Add this templates (templates may change in future):

```
*_*Factory.java
*_ComponentTreeDeps.java
*_Factory.java
*_GeneratedInjector.java
*_HiltComponents.java
*_HiltModules.java
*_HiltModules_BindsModule.java
*_HiltModules_KeyModule.java
*_MembersInjector.java
*_ProvideFactory.java
*_SingletonC.java
*_TestComponentDataSupplier.java
BR.java
BuildConfig.java
DataBinderMapperImpl.java
Hilt_*.java
_test_*.java
```

##### 2. Exclude 'Codegen' from index

Open `Go to File`, choose tab `Files` and then click `Filter` and uncheck `Codegen` file-type.
[image: uncheck codegen]

**That's all!**

After this when you will run tests with code coverage (with IntelliJ IDEA runner), matched Codegen-files will be excluded also from code coverage report in IDE.

---

*Note: With this approach you can't get coverage from CLI. If you need get coverage from CLI - use Jacoco.*

Comment: That worked for me! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: sweet :) 
I just added *_*.java cause I only write in kotlin :D

Answer (score 5):

More recent versions of Dagger generate additional files with slightly different patterns. I had success with the following excludes when using Dagger 2.15

```
'**/*_MembersInjector.class',
'**/Dagger*Component*.class',
'**/Dagger*Subcomponent*.class',
'**/*Subcomponent$Builder.class',
'**/*Module_*Factory.class',
```